# How to stop Adobe Edge Animate stretching the symbol when you try to match dimensions of the inner div

Tags: adobe, adobe-edge

this is a weird issue.
I'm creating an adaptive banner, small, medium and large screens.

I create the label and created a new animation on that part of the time line.

I turned it into a symbol. But I noticed the area was clipping my animation and had to increase the height.

So I edited the symbol and increased the stage height.
Great 350px to 500px high

When I went back up to the main stage I noticed the sumbol was still clipping the animation. So I tried to increase the height of the symbol, but instead of matching it to its marquee area it is stretching the elements within the symbol when I resize it so how do I resize it to match the stage area within the symbol so that it does not clip.

Note switching overflow to visible does resolve the issue but it is not neat.

[image: Main Stage... light blue line is the stage area of the symbol, dark line is the size of symbol on the main stage]
[image: If I resize the height the symbol also resizes, but I wo not want it to do this I want it to match the light blue line, ie reveal as if you were to reveal more canvas area in a masked area]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

regards,

Andi

Answer (score 0):

There was no "real" answer I could find for this. Everything I tried did not work.
The only thing I could do was to take the elements out of the Symbol.

Put them on the main stage and create a new symbol from those.

Might be one for the Adobe Edge team to work out.